# Inserting a map in database using jdbctemplate

Tags: java, jdbctemplate

I have a map in java.

I want to insert it into database table using JdbcTemplate.

I wrote below code for the same:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : myMap.entrySet()) {
System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue());

this.stgdbJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(this.myInsertQuery, new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {

@Override
public void setValues(final PreparedStatement ps, final int i) throws SQLException {
    ps.setString(1, entry.getKey());
    ps.setString(2, entry.getValue());
}
});
}
```

Here myMap is a local variable as below:

```
 Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

However, I am getting below error:

```
Cannot refer to a non-final variable entry inside an inner class defined in a different method
```

What could be the solution to this ?

Updated code:

```
for (final Map.Entry<String, String> entry : myMap.entrySet()) {
System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue());

this.stgdbJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(this.myInsertQuery, new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {

@Override
public void setValues(final PreparedStatement ps, final int i) throws SQLException {
    ps.setString(1, entry.getKey());
    ps.setString(2, entry.getValue());
}

public int getBatchSize() {
                    return finalFields.size();
            }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define entry as final like this:

```
for (final Map.Entry<String, String> entry : myMap.entrySet())
```

Comment: How to include size of myMap to define batch size: Please see updated code!

Comment: Same thing: Declare myMap final.